# PyDev program output in debug console

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, console, pydev

Please bear with me if this is very basic, as I'm quite new to PyDev. Is there some way to redirect the program output to a PyDev debug console? I'm referring to something like in Matlab. As of now, I have one console for the output where I cannot enter commands, and another in interactive mode. It's not the most convenient thing to keep switching between the two while debugging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is the interactive console:

Check http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

After having it open, you can execute a file and have its tokens available with Ctrl+Alt+Enter (which is also the binding to open it... and you can do a selection and send only some of the contents to it too).

Comment: Thanks! I already had a look at this.It doesn't seem to do what I expect when I try it in PyDev. I actually switched back to Vi + iPython + Pdb now and it's much better.

Comment: Just for information purposes, what exactly were you expecting?

Comment: Something like the standard Python/iPython console where it's the same window for typing in commands, viewing output, etc. When I tried that, there were two separate windows, one for the console and the other for stdout. I still had to keep switching between the two. Does that make sense? :-S

Comment: Actually, you can type commands directly in the interactive console in PyDev (the option to send contents to the console with Ctrl+Alt+Enter is just an additional choice to allow you to send contents from a file directly to the console without having to ctrl+c/ctrl+v)